# My CSS positioning is unstable. How can I stabilize it?

Tags: html, css, css-position

The elements of the web page I'm building move around when I want them to stay in place. If the line beginning "This is a Beta version" changes length, the 4 menu items (translucent gray rectangles) shift: If I shorten the bottom line, the menu items move to the right; if I lengthen it, the menu items move left.

How can I arrange things so that the width of one element won't change the horizontal position of other elements that are stacked vertically with it?

You can view the page at http://apdamien.info/nfair/GH/demo/mainmenu.html

Here is what I think is the relevant sections of the code:
CSS:

```
#mainmenu {
    width: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

#maindiv {
    background: url(imgs/smalltown.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.menu-entry {
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 39px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Univers,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    margin-left: 8em;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(96,96,96,0.65);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu-entry:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

And the relevant chunk of HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="titleauth">
  <div id="title"><img alt="Demo Game" src="imgs/title.svg"/></div>
  <div id="author"><a href="http://www.apdamien.info"
        target="_blank"><img alt="A. P. Damien" src="imgs/author.svg"/></a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lowerleft">
      <div id="mainmenu">
        <a class="menu-entry" href="game.html">New Game</a>
        <a class="menu-entry" href="helpmain.html">How to Play</a>
        <a class="menu-entry" href="restore.html">Restore Saved Game</a>
        <a class="menu-entry" href="credits.html">Credits</a>
      </div>
      <div id="bottom-line">
        <img alt="Beta version warning" src="imgs/beta.svg" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `#mainmenu` and `#bottom-line` are positioned relative to the left-hand side of `#lowerleft`. If you want to have them positioned relative to the *right*-hand side, you'll need to float all children to the right. You'll also want to use `clear: both`, so that the children won't sit next to each other.

```
#lowerleft * {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Using the above on your live site allows me to adjust the width of `#bottom-line` without affecting the postion of `#mainmenu`, so this should hopefully work for you :)

Note that this shifts the menu slightly to the right. If you want to move the main menu back to its original position, you can increase its `margin-right` value. It would have had no effect on the menu previously, though the addition of `float: right` also fixes that ;)